# How to avoid URL and directory match problem when editing .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following lines in the **.htaccess** file in the site directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{1}[a-z0-9_-]{3,20})$ account.php?username=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

If it receives URL for example :

```
http://localhost/samplesite/johnsmith
```

it will rewrite it to

```
http://localhost/samplesite/account.php?username=johnsmith
```

which is fine.

The problem occurs when there is a directory named **johnsmith** in the site directory. then the URL is rewritten to and displayed as

```
http://localhost/samplesite/johnsmith/?username=johnsmith
```

and that is a problem. I am trying to implement account pages functionality for every user but if a user wants to register a username like some directory in the root the functionality will break? I tried adding rewrite conditions to check if the requested URL stands for an existing directory or a file  :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

but I don't know how to proceed.

If someone knows a better way to do account pages functionality for users I would appreciate to give me a piece of advice on that.

Can anybody help me solve this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteCond` will work if it is in the correct place.  Your full .htaccess should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# ---------------------------------------------------------------See info below--
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{1}[a-z0-9_-]{3,20})$ account.php?username=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Also, you don't need the `%{QUERY_STRING}`.  Instead you should use the `QSA` flag to append the rest of the query string...

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{1}[a-z0-9_-]{3,20})$ account.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yes, at last my lines in the .htaccess files look like your code. But the problem is not yet solved. How to resolve it if I have the same directory and username available? Or are there any better solutions to this problematic situation?

Comment: The first answer to my question did not resolve the issue! Does anyone know how to prevent the problem? It is in the matching names of directory and account username. The functionality is like the one in facebook -  I want to do the same as http://www.facebook.com/johnsmith/ for example. I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @forbdn I don't think you'll be able to solve this with .htaccess.  Instead, all requests would have to go first to `index.php` to check the database to see if a record exists.  If not, PHP would then have to check if the directory exists and redirect there if it does.